# I can´t link the style to html in Sublime Text

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to style my webpage but it´s not working. I´ve tried everything.

The folders and files are set up correctly.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi there my friend</h1>
        <p id=welcome>Welcome to my page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
#welcome {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML the id name must be between inverted commas.

```
 <p id="welcome">Welcome to my page</p>
```

Comment: What is the difference between Riyas Ac's answer and your.

Answer (score 0):

Please add id with double quotes

```
<p id="welcome">Welcome to my page</p>
```

Comment: Check now @Sigge Thorén

Answer (score 0):

Try using Class Example :

```
<p class="welcome">Welcome To My Page </p>
```

css

```
 .welcome{font-size:12px}
```

But here you are using **id** here So use ,

```
<p id="welcome">Welcome to my page</p>
```

css

```
#welcome{font-size:12px}
```

Hope This will help You, Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You must put class and id name in Double Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide id attribute in double quotation marks.

`<p id="welcome">Welcome to my page</p>`